# Percentage to Factor

Tags: c#, numbers, percentage

So I am trying to calculate the profit in euros. The data I have is `SoldValue` and `Profit`. The "Profit" comes in 1.22345356, except for me to calculate the bought value I need it to be 1.0122345356. I don't know how to add "1.0" or "1." (when the profit is 10% or higher). I have tried to convert the double to a string then add "1.0" or "1," in front of it and then convert it back to a double. I am new to C#, so don't blame me for coding. :)

My code:

```
double Percentage = 1.22345356;
double SoldValue = 0.16644;

string F = "1.0" + Percentage;
double Factor = Convert.ToDouble(F);

double BoughtValue = SoldValue / Factor;

double Profit = SoldValue - BoughtValue;
```

Result: `101,22345356` instead of `1,0122345356`.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time trying to understand your question.  Is `Profit` a string?

Comment: @iamJP `Profit` is a double in the OP's code.  Is the comma throwing you off?  In Europe the decimal separator is a `,` instead of `.`

Comment: Won't `1.0+(Percentage/100)` do it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it was thanks, now i'm looking up international numeric conventions

Comment: @maccettura I was also thrown off by that, thanks for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not do string manipulation and type conversion to get the percentage right, because it is harder to get right for all percentages, and possibly slower than a pure numerical approach.

Instead the factor can be calculated like this:

```
double factor = (100.0 + Percentage) / 100.0;
```

The basic idea here is to add the percentage to 100 (percent) and then divide it by 100 to "normalize" / scale it back to values like `1.something`.

That way, when percentage is 1.2, the factor will be 1.012.